# Use a PIR Sensor to detect the movements of a paper

Tags: sensors

I need to detect when a paper comes out from a laser printer and count the number of printed papers. For that I hope to use a PIR sensor to detect the movement of the paper from the printer. Is it possible to detect the movement of a paper using a PIR sensor? Please be kind enough to help me.

Answer (score 3):

If the paper is hot when it comes out of the printer, possibly.  Could be unreliable though.

Better would be to place a photo-interrupter (or IR LED and IR Photodiode) in the path of the paper to detect a break in an infra-red beam.

Answer (score 2):

The solution from the OP with the photo-interruptor is probably the most standard one.

However it might be worth checking if you can get away with a light sensor: assuming that the paper is mostly of different colour than the background, the paper should change the current passing through the photodiode.

Alternatively, you could use a proximity sensor, aimed at a location on the path of the paper, where there is typically nothing.

These 2 solutions are trying to avoid having to place something on both sides of the paper. If that doesn't bother you, then I'd recommend the OP's solution.

Comment: A "light sensor" that relies on ambient light may be rather subject to changes in external conditions.  If using anything open to the environment it's really best to provide your own light source that is modulated and look for that pattern in the receiver, at least with an op-amp filter, and possibly with something as discriminating as a lock-in amplifier (which is fairly easy in software - it ends up a lot like a single point fourier transform)